# Error: "The file is damaged and could not be repaired." while rendering ServerReport

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, reportviewer

I am facing below error while rendering PDF report on ReportViewer.

[image]

Below is the code causing this issue:

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
string mimeType = string.Empty;
string encoding = string.Empty;
string extension = string.Empty;
byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=myfile");
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

The fix that worked for me was to add the below line of code at the end.

```
Response.End();
```